# Azure storage emulator unable to initialize

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-emulator

I've upgraded Azure Storage Emulator from 2.3 to 2.4. *WAStorageEmulator.exe* has been renamed to *AzureStorageEmulator.exe* but that's not the issue.

When I run

```
AzureStorageEmulator init -forcecreate
```

I simply get an error that Google returns with **zero** results:

> Error: User-specified instance not found. Please correct this and re-run initial
>   ization.

### Edit

I had to do a start and stop and then I was able to init. Because I had previous version of emulator installed I already have *WAStorageEmulatorDb34* on my local SQL server instance. After I run *init* command I can see that **no new database is being created** (like *WAStorageEmulatorDb42*).

So I thought that the newest version may be using older DB. I then ran a query in MSSMS to check for existing blob containers and I can still see both containers I created on the older emulator containing blobs I added.

When I then accessed Development Azure Storage in Visual Studio it showed no containers whatsoever. So the new version apparently doesn't use old DB. **But which one?** And **where is it**?

Ok so I thought I'd run init one more time but with additional parameters to put DB on my SQL server instance:

```
AzureStorageEmulator init -server localhost -sqlinstance MSSQLSERVER -forcecreate
```

And then I get the aforementioned error. Again...

I'm running CMD as admin with elevated permissions.

Comment: Try "/forceCreate" instead of "-forceCreate"

     AzureStorageEmulator init /forceCreate

Comment: @FabrizioAccatino I had to do a *start* and *stop* and then I was able to run *init*... Regardless of using minus or slash... BUT. My preexisting DB WAStorageEmulator34 is still there, but no new database is being created? This existing DB has two containers, but when I access Storage Emulator from within VS I see nothing as one would expect when initialization with *-forcecreate* would reinitialize DB. So I wonder **which database is this latest emulator using** and **where is it**?

Comment: @FabrizioAccatino: See my edited question

Comment: AFAIK db files are not compatible across different version of Storage Emulator. I had emulator 4.1 and now 4.2.  Under c:\users\fabry\ I see two localdb files: AzureStorageEmulatorDb41.mdf and AzureStorageEmulatorDb42.mdf   I know that everytime I update the storage-emulator, I start with an emtpy repository.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Solution that eventually worked

> #### Additional info
>
> Azure Storage Emulator normally creates tables in the LocalDB storage. Depending on the emulator version these may be in various DB instances. You can check each storage emulator version's configuration in
>
> ```
> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\[AzureStorageEmulatorFolder]\*.config
> ```
>
> Different versions have different folder names from *DevelopmentStorage*, *WAStorageEmulator* to latest (4.2) *AzureStorageEmulator*.
>
> In this subfolder you'll find at least one config file that will correspond to your installed Azure storage emulator's version. If you open it, you'll see how it's configured and where it saved its tables. This is also true if you create initialization on any existing full SQL server instance.

The problem when I was trying to initialize my Azure Storage Emulator (ASE) is that I was also providing SQL server's instance which is the default one (MSSQLSERVER). I shouldn't be providing this information in the first place but only provide information about server

So the correct command line call is

```
AzureStorageEmulator init -server localhost -forcecreate
```

This created my database on my local SQL server. From here on, it's up to you how you'll migrate from an existing ASE database (if you already had one before) to the new one.

Comment: This worked for me.  I had removed some older versions of SQL Server from my machine and it seems the emulator was relying on one of them.  Couldn't work out how to get it initialised until I saw your suggestion - I guess the forcecreate flag is the key.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue I ran into is more or less an user error.

Azure Storage Emulator 4.6

> Error :  User-specified instance not found. Please correct this and
>   re-run initialization.

and

> Resolution :  I didn't have a windows authenticated login to my local
>   sql instance.